# flexible http JavaScript "file.js" include in html page

Tags: javascript, html, http

my problem is that i have to include some scripts over http. I'm seerching for a flexable solution were I can change the IP-Address over an textbox.

Now I do in html head so:

**src="http://192.168.1.103:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"**

Or is it possible to do the http include in JavaScript?

thank, martin

Comment: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from the question you asked you want to load a javascript from different IP addresses.which will be provided by user through text box and loads dynamically. For that i have return a sample code and pasting it below already tested on FireFox.Enter IP address in the text box and press the 'LoadJs' button.

snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var src=":8000/socket.io/socket.io.js";

function changeIp()
{
    var temp = '<script src=http://'+ $('#stack_id_ip').val() + src;
    temp = temp +' />';
    $('body').append(temp);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="stack_id_ip"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeIp()" value="LoadJS"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to Jquery that made my job easy to answer :)